# How to use SSH with an unstable internet connection?

Tags: ssh, connection, udp

Sometimes, I'm forced to use ssh over an unstable internet connection.

```
ping some.doma.in
PING some.doma.in (x.x.x.x): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
64 bytes from x.x.x.x: icmp_seq=3 ttl=44 time=668.824 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
Request timeout for icmp_seq 6
Request timeout for icmp_seq 7
64 bytes from x.x.x.x: icmp_seq=8 ttl=44 time=719.034 ms
```

Is there a way to use tools to increase the reliability of tcp connections (above all ssh)?

I imagine something like an SSH proxy, that runs on a machine with a decent connection, that will receive UDP packets, order them using a higher network layer protocol, forward them to the destination server using ssh and reply to the origin.

Or are there any ssh command line switches to enable more data redundancy or anything else to avoid "broken pipes"?

Or maybe a client-server application that uses the bittorrent network to distribute packets, and allows to forward commands to ssh back-and-forth. (=high latency but high reliability)

// I tried screen and stuff but sometimes the connection is just too unreliable to enable efficient working.

Cheers and thx in advance!

Comment: Just to point out that SSH doesn't actually use SSL/TLS. (Your question suggests you believe this may be the case.)

Comment: Thanks Bruno, I learned something and changed the text! :)
By the way, I found http://mosh.mit.edu/ which might be what I'm looking for... Let's see.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After some more research and some luck, I stumbled upon mosh.

http://mosh.mit.edu

It's amazing. A client-server implementation using UDP and lots of small little things (like echo prediction). Everyone should use it.

Comment: The link seems dead, and https://mosh.org is a replacement.